# Can I render and set HTML5 canvas into HTML IMAGE's source?

Tags: image, html, canvas

Is there a way to render Canvas in offscreen into HTML IMAGE element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`img.src = canvas.toDataURL();`

where `img` and `canvas` are the respective element object (from `document.getElementByElement(...)`).

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask another way without conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by 'without conversion'?

Comment: Canvas will render the image as bitmap in memory, and the method look encoding it into PNG. So, if I use the method, I have to decode it from PNG. This will decrease performance greatly. I want to avoid this encoding/decoding cost because I want to display real-time rendered animation between HTML elements.

Comment: Then why don't you display the `<canvas>` element directly? It would be the fastest way coz in some browsers that come with hw acceleration, you are essentially accessing pixel at GPU directly. You many also consider using two `<canvas>`s, one onscreen one offscreen, and copy pixels between them using `drawImage()`.

Comment: Because no element can be displayed on <canvas>, there is no way to display <video> in <canvas>. It's acceptable slow UI on slow machine. I can stop animation effects on the slow machines. But my app should display video inside of <canvas> display area.

Comment: And what I want to do is not manipulating each pixels. I just want to pass rendered graphics into <img> as image source. On general GPU logic, this can be done with only passing a texture pointer :)